# G110: Potential DoS vulnerability via decompression bomb (gosec)

Tags: go, static-analysis, golint

I'm getting the following `golintci` message:

```
testdrive/utils.go:92:16: G110: Potential DoS vulnerability via decompression bomb (gosec)
    if _, err := io.Copy(targetFile, fileReader); err != nil {
                 ^
```

Read the corresponding [CWE](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/409.html) and I'm not clear on how this is expected to be corrected.

Please offer pointers.

```
func unzip(archive, target string) error {
    reader, err := zip.OpenReader(archive)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, file := range reader.File {
        path := filepath.Join(target, file.Name) // nolint: gosec
        if file.FileInfo().IsDir() {
            if err := os.MkdirAll(path, file.Mode()); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            continue
        }

        fileReader, err := file.Open()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer fileReader.Close() // nolint: errcheck

        targetFile, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, file.Mode())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer targetFile.Close() // nolint: errcheck

        if _, err := io.Copy(targetFile, fileReader); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62446118/implicit-memory-aliasing-in-for-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on various pointers provided, replaced

```
if _, err := io.Copy(targetFile, fileReader); err != nil {
  return err
}
```

with

```
for {
  _, err := io.CopyN(targetFile, fileReader, 1024)
  if err != nil {
    if err == io.EOF {
      break
    }
    return err
  }
}
```

PS while this helps memory footprint, this wouldn't help a DDOS attack copying very long and/or infinite stream ...

Comment: I think the benefit of chunking is that you can have additional logic in the loop to mitigate the impact of a decompression attack, but this of course depends on the specifics of your application.

Comment: Also, I am wondering if the replacement should use `errors.Is(err, io.EOF)`

Answer (score 7):

The warning you get comes from a rule provided in [gosec](https://github.com/securego/gosec).

The rule specifically detects usage of `io.Copy` on file decompression.

This is a potential issue because [`io.Copy`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy):

> copies from `src` to `dst` until either EOF is reached on `src` or an error occurs.

So, a malicious payload might cause your program to decompress an unexpectedly big amount of data and go out of memory, causing denial of service as mentioned in the warning message.

In particular, gosec will check ([source](https://github.com/securego/gosec/blob/master/rules/decompression-bomb.go#L85)) the AST of your program and warn you about usage of `io.Copy` or `io.CopyBuffer` together with any one of the following:

- `"compress/gzip".NewReader`
- `"compress/zlib".NewReader` or `NewReaderDict`
- `"compress/bzip2".NewReader`
- `"compress/flate".NewReader` or `NewReaderDict`
- `"compress/lzw".NewReader`
- `"archive/tar".NewReader`
- `"archive/zip".NewReader`
- `"*archive/zip".File.Open`

Using [`io.CopyN`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#CopyN) removes the warning because (quote) it "*copies n bytes (or until an error) from src to dst*", thus giving you (the program writer) control of how many bytes to copy. So you could pass an arbitrarily large `n` that you set based on the  available resources of your application, or [copy in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40429443/4108803).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're working on compressed data, you need to use `io.CopyN`.
You can try a workaround with `--nocompress` flag. But this will cause the data to be included uncompressed.

See the following PR and related issue : https://github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata/pull/50